# Popup window in ASP with image

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Can I have a popup window in ASP page when I click on a hyperlink? And on that popup, can I display my image?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most basic way would be `<a href="path_to_image" target="_blank">link text</a>` which will open the link in a new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<A HREF="javascript:void(0)"
onclick="window.open('images/myimage.jpg',
'imagePop','width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes,
location=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
Open a new window</A>
```

Change the yes values to no if you don't want them, experiment!